# How can I deblur an image in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I need to remove the blur this image:

[image]

Image source: http://www.flickr.com/photos/63036721@N02/5733034767/

Any Ideas?

Comment: You cannot magically add detail.

Comment: You can look in to wavelet deblurring methods. Those work quite well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although previous answers are right when they say that you can't recover lost information, you could investigate a little and make a few guesses.

I downloaded your image in what seems to be the original size (75x75) and you can see here a  zoomed segment (one little square = one pixel)

[image]

It seems a pretty linear grayscale! Let's verify it by plotting the intensities of the central row. In Mathematica:

```
ListLinePlot[First /@ ImageData[i][[38]][[1 ;; 15]]]
```

[image]

So, it is effectively linear, starting at zero and ending at one.

So you may guess it was originally a B&W image, linearly blurred.

The easiest way to deblur that (not always giving good results, but enough in your case) is to binarize the image with a 0.5 threshold. Like this:

[image]

And this is a possible way. Just remember we are guessing a lot here!

HTH!

Comment: Or, in Matlab syntax: `binaryImage = img>0.5;`

Comment: @Jonas Tnx! No Matlab spoken here.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot generally retrieve missing information.

If you know what it is an image of, in this case a Gaussian or Airy profile then it's probably an out of focus image of a point source - you can determine the characteristics of the point.

Another technique is to try and determine the character tics of the blurring - especially if you have many images form the same blurred system. Then iteratively create a possible source image, blur it by that convolution and compare it to the blurred image.
This is the general technique used to make radio astronomy source maps (images) and was used for the flawed Hubble Space Telescope images

Answer (score 1):

When working with images one of the most common things is to use a convolution filter.  There is a "sharpen" filter that does what it can to remove blur from an image.  An example of a sharpen filter can be found here:
http://www.panoramafactory.com/sharpness/sharpness.html

Some programs like matlab make convolution really easy: conv2(A,B)
And most nice photo editing have the filters under some name or another (sharpen usually).

But keep in mind that filters can only do so much.  In theory, the actual information has been lost by the blurring process and it is impossible to perfectly reconstruct the initial image (no matter what TV will lead you to believe).

In this case it seems like you have a very simple image with only black and white.  Knowing this about your image you could always use a simple threshold.  Set everything above a certain threshold to white, and everything below to black.  Once again most photo editing software makes this really easy.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot retrieve missing information, but under certain assumptions you can sharpen.

[Try unsharp masking.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking)