# Deblurring an image in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, blur

I was unable to find a solution to this problem posted in this thread

[How can I deblur an image in matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075129/how-can-i-deblur-an-image-in-matlab)

As suggested ,the image obtained after applying unsharp filter is

[image: http://tinypic.com/r/14bib77/6]

But the blurirness is not removed even after the unsharp filter. Can anyone suggest any other methods?

Comment: Use a larger radius on the filter. But be aware that there is no magic - it will take a lot of filter tuning and you probably won't be completely happy with the results.

Answer (score 3):

Deblurring is an [inverse problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem), and like most inverse problems there is no easy solution. So do not expect any magical method.

Having said that, there are some widely used methods for deblurring. [Wiener deconvolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution) is one of the most popular methods used for deblurring.

For Wiener filtering in Matlab, see http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/bqqhk8f.html